# FileManager replaceItemAt() results in EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: swift3, exc-bad-access, ios10, nsfilemanager

I've written an application that downloads images from a website.
If this image already exists on the device I'm trying to replace it.

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
    let userId = Int.init(downloadTask.taskDescription!)! // task description is definetly set in downloadImage() and is an Int
    guard let target = imageFolder?.appendingPathComponent("\(userId).jpg") else {
        delegate?.imageDownloadFailed(forUser: userId, error: "Could not create target URL.")
        return
    }

    do {
        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: target.path) {
            _ = try fileManager.replaceItemAt(target, withItemAt: location)
        } else {
            try fileManager.moveItem(at: location, to: target)
        }
        delegate?.savedImage(forUser: userId, at: target)
    } catch let error {
        delegate?.imageDownloadFailed(forUser: userId, error: error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

The problem occurs in the `if`-statement:

```
_ = try fileManager.replaceItemAt(target, withItemAt: location)
```

I always got `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` and I can't find the error.
`fileManager`, `target`, and `location` are non-nil.
I've already tried to dispatch the code synchronous to the main thread, but the error still persists.

Any advices?

#### Edit:

Since I'm not the only one who got this error I decided to create a bug report at Apple.
The report is available at Open Radar; [click](https://openradar.appspot.com/28755011)

I've also uploaded a [playground file at pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/bQrgX1Gs) which demonstrates the error and provides a quick solution similar to the one of [naudec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39930482/filemanager-replaceitemat-results-in-exc-bad-access/39986213#39986213).

Comment: No advice but I am facing the exact same issue in my project as well. This time not within a closure. Like you I either replace or move the item. The move operation works but replace will always fail with EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: I've created a bug report [Open Radar link](https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5491122952470528)

Comment: Seems to be fixed in Xcode Version 8.2 (8C38).

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue. Ended up writing my own version:

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default

func copyItem(at srcURL: URL, to dstURL: URL) {
    do {
        try fileManager.copyItem(at: srcURL, to: dstURL)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        if error.code == NSFileWriteFileExistsError {
            print("File exists. Trying to replace")
            replaceItem(at: dstURL, with: srcURL)
        }
    }
}

func replaceItem(at dstURL: URL, with srcURL: URL) {
    do {
        try fileManager.removeItem(at: dstURL)
        copyItem(at: srcURL, to: dstURL)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

I call `copyItem` first.

Answer (score 0):

The class holding this method does not exist any more at the time your download finishes and did release your `filemanager`. Create the `FileManager` within your completion closure:

```
...
let localFilemanager = FileManager.default
do {
...
```

Comment: I've already tried that. The exception is still there. Also, the boolean evaluation of the if statement works fine. The variable exists at the time the call occurs.

Comment: Within your `if` clause, print `fileManager`, `target`and `location` to igure out the trouble maker.

Comment: Then please update your question with what you already tried, the results of those tries (log) and the exact error (address(es))